# rename multiple files with date of file with powershell

Tags: powershell, date, rename

So far I have used this:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "OLD-FILE-NAME-PART",""}
```

to erase and replace.

But at the end of each file I want to include the file date. Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the filenames and desired output?

Comment: Just like "something 06-22-2020.PDF" and I just got "something 06222020.PDF"

Comment: So for input `06-22-2020.PDF` you want `06222020.PDF` as the new filename?

Comment: If the file has the date 06-22-2020, I just want to get 22-06-2020 but getting from the file's date

Comment: please, put additional info in your Question. also, it would seriously help to have two or three _detailed_ before-and-after examples ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.Basename -replace "OLD-FILE-NAME-PART","" ) + 
    $_.CreationTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".$_.Extension"}
```